# Javascript string into array depth object

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sorry if the title is confusing, I'm confused my self.

So its like this, I get a string from api like this: 'data.data.type'.

And I need to turn it into this response['data]['data]['type'].

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: (do you want to return the **string** `"response['data']['data']['type']"` or that property of an existing object `response`?)

Comment: the later one, the property of an existing object

Comment: u can try `response.split(".")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming response is a single object , you can get the value of `type` like this

```js
var response = {
  data: {
    data: {
      type: "Here is type"
    }
  }
}

console.log(response['data']['data']['type'])
```